# How to change the fontfamily of items in flyoutpicker of combobox in wp8.1

Tags: xaml, combobox, windows-phone-8.1, font-family

Can anyone explain, how to change the fontfamily of the flyoutpicker(the overflow menu that appears when there are more than 5 items in a combobox) ?

I've tried many ways, but not able to get the solution.

Please help.

The link to the screenshot ->
https://i.stack.imgur.com/237XW.png

I somehow mananged to change the header font[marked by yellow rectangle] and also the background colour[marked red *]

But i want to change the font family of the text[marked by red rectangle].

Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to override **ListPickerFlyoutPresenter**

```
<Style TargetType="ListPickerFlyoutPresenter">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource MyFontFamily" />
<Style/>
```

---

### UPDATE:

You need override following DataTemplate for customizing FontFamily

```
<!-- DataTemplate holding the content for ListPickerFlyoutPresenter's ItemsHostPanel -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListPickerFlyoutPresenterContentTemplate">
    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="32"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource LoraBoldFontFamily}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.Footer>
            <Border Height="{ThemeResource ListPickerFlyoutFooterThemeHeight}" Width="1" />
        </ListView.Footer>
    </ListView>
</DataTemplate>
```

Donwnload sample from [OneDrive](http://1drv.ms/1gzojBx)

Comment: I didn't get what i wanted... :-(

Comment: You wanted to change font family for combobox items in list picker flyout :)

Comment: but i not able to do that... I'm trying from 2 days.. :-(